# Database language organization, by word or by language?

Tags: mongodb

I seek to add a dictionary for sentences (that most are single words) but am undecided if I should organize them by words, such as:

```
{word:"bacon", en:"bacon", ro:"sunca", fr:"jambon"}
```

or by language:

```
{
    en:{ bacon:bacon },
    ro:{ bacon:sunca },
    fr:{ bacon:jambon }
}
```

I realize both have pros and cons, are equally valid, but I am seeking the wisdom of those who met this problem before, made a choice, and are happy or regret to have made it, and of course, why.

Thank you.

Comment: no one can answer that question without knowing how you will be using these data.  What kind of queries will you be making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below representation is simple and elegant. But the document representation in mongodb (or most nosql databases for that matter) is heavily influenced by the usage pattern of the data.

```
{word:"bacon", en:"bacon", ro:"sunca", fr:"jambon"}
```

This representation has the below merits assuming you want to look-up the other language translation by passing in the `word`

1. Intitive
2. No duplication
3. You can have index on the `word`

Comment: the index by the word sold me

Answer (score 0):

Of the two options that you provide, the first one is better. But since there will be at most so many languages, in your case, I would actually go for arrays:

```
LANG = {en: 0, ro: 1, fr: 2}
DICT = [
  [:ham, :sunca, :jambon],
  [:egg, :ou, :œuf]
]
```

For translation, write eg:

```
def translate( word, from: nil, to: nil )
  from = LANG[from]
  to = LANG[to]
  i = DICT.index { |entry| entry[from] == word }
  return DICT[i][to]
end

translate( :egg, from: :en, to: :fr )
#=> :œuf
```

Note please, that although effort has been done to minimize the size of the dictionary, as for the speed, faster matching algorithms would be available, using eg. suffix trees.

Comment: From MongoDB perspective the array approach does not allow for efficient indexing (and thus search).

Comment: Nice to know that. Haven't been interested in Mongo that much up until now, but I guess it's my time to be interested more.